# jQuery layout many nested layouts

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

If I have many nested layouts, then I need to identify each of the layout container (parents of divs with class `ui-layout-center`) and manually call `layout()` on each of them. As I have no IDs set on each of the layout containers, my idea was to get all containers and just call `layout()` on all of them automatically, like this:

```
    $(".ui-layout-center").parent().layout({
        applyDefaultStyles : true
    });
```

But that does not work as only the topmost layout seems to be `layout()`ed.
The question now is what it is wrong with my jquery selection/code.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging, I found out that my assumption was wrong on how jquery was iterating over the selection. So, the solution was this:

```
    $(".ui-layout-center").each(function() {
        $(this).parent().layout({
            applyDefaultStyles : true
        });
    });
```